# YII2 - how to render a view inside active-form

Tags: yii2, modal-dialog

i'm trying to render view from another controller in active form when creating new data. my purpose is only for reference when render the view. how to achieve this in yii2?
ilustration like this : active form in `controller-B/create` and there is a button to view the modal `(controller-A/list)` and select data what user want and then render a view beside active form `(controller-A/view?id=xx)`.
[image: render a view in the active form]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking?

Comment: when input new data in controller B, i want also view data from controller A for reference. user click search button, show up the modal and click what data want to view for reference.

Comment: your "another view" is in modal or simple view?

Comment: simple view is ok.

Comment: as far as i understand, you need to use ajax and render that "another view" on what user want to view for reference. Minimal code to produce your scenario is required. add code.

Comment: yeah. that's right. i will add my code

Comment: this is [my code](https://pastebin.com/7P6mPrPD)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160677/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-wilson-ng).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$view = $this->render('view', [
    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
]);

return json_encode($view);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        // ActiveForm code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="whatever" style="display:none"> // initially hidden
       // render another view here
   </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.select-row', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $.get('../pengiriman-produksi/get-data', {id : id}, function(data){
       var data = $.parseJSON(data);    
       $('#whatever').show();
       $('#whatever').html(data);
   });
   $('#modalPengiriman').modal('hide');        
});
```

Comment: you're very helpful Insane. Thanks.